# Stationary vs. Trend-Stationary Time Series: Auto.Arima difference parameter

Tags: r, time-series, arima, stationarity

I have the following time series `training_ts` that looks like this:

[image: Training Data Time Series]

It appears to be stationary or "trend-stationary".  When I analyze the stationarity using `adf` and `kpss` as well as `nsdiffs`, I receive the following output:

```
> adf.test(training_ts)

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  training_ts
Dickey-Fuller = -5.5779, Lag order = 11, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(training_ts) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> kpss.test(training_ts, null = c("Level"))

KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  training_ts
KPSS Level = 10.369, Truncation lag parameter = 9, p-value = 0.01

Warning message:
In kpss.test(training_ts, null = c("Level")) :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
> kpss.test(training_ts, null = c("Trend"))

KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  training_ts
KPSS Trend = 0.52976, Truncation lag parameter = 9, p-value = 0.01

Warning message:
In kpss.test(training_ts, null = c("Trend")) :
  p-value smaller than printed p-value
> nsdiffs(training_ts)
[1] 0
```

All of which seems to suggest that `training_ts` is indeed stationary. My next step is then to use the `auto.arima` package to do some forecasting with external regressors (`training_xregs`).  However, the model that `auto.arima` returns is a `d = 1` model, which is counterintuitive given that the `nsdiff, adf.test, kpss.test` output suggests `training_ts` is already stationary. Here is the `auto.arima` output:

```
> arima_model = auto.arima(y = training_ts, trace = TRUE, approximation = 
TRUE, xreg = training_xregs[, 2:ncol(training_xregs)])

 Fitting models using approximations to speed things up...

 Regression with ARIMA(2,1,2)(1,0,1)[7] errors : 9939.105
 Regression with ARIMA(0,1,0)           errors : 10624.08
 Regression with ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[7] errors : 10289.05
 Regression with ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,1)[7] errors : 9949.029
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                              : 10622.07
 Regression with ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,1)[7] errors : 9936.425
 Regression with ARIMA(2,1,2)           errors : 9944.379
 Regression with ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,2)[7] errors : 9935.7
 Regression with ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,0,2)[7] errors : 9933.618
 Regression with ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,2)[7] errors : 9932.408
 Regression with ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,2)[7] errors : 10623.19
 ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9930.753
 ARIMA(1,1,1)(1,0,2)[7]                    : 9934.871
 ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,1)[7]                    : 9931.152
 ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9946.309
 ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9932.426
 ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 10279.04
 ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9931.963
 ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 10621.17
 ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9934.051

 Now re-fitting the best model(s) without approximations...

 ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,2)[7]                    : 9934.814

 Best model: Regression with ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,2)[7] errors
```

So `auto.arima` believes that `training_ts` is not a stationary time series. Which is confusing given the above.

I then used `auto.arima` to specify a `d=0` difference order with the following results:

```
> arima_model = auto.arima(y = training_ts, d = 0, trace = TRUE, approximation = TRUE, xreg = training_xregs[, 2:ncol(training_xregs)])

 Fitting models using approximations to speed things up...

 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9937.261
 ARIMA(0,0,0)           with non-zero mean : 11318.17
 ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[7] with non-zero mean : 10311.81
 ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 10593.26
 ARIMA(0,0,0)           with zero mean     : 11343.59
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(0,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(2,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9945.74
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,0)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,0,2)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)           with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(2,0,2)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,2)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9937.014
 ARIMA(1,0,1)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9937.009
 ARIMA(0,0,2)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,4)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9941.742
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] with zero mean     : 9937.686
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(0,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(2,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9945.782
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,0)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,2)[7] with non-zero mean : 9939.034
 ARIMA(1,0,3)           with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,3)(2,0,2)[7] with non-zero mean : 9944.402
 ARIMA(0,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9939.694
 ARIMA(1,0,4)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9938.988

 Now re-fitting the best model(s) without approximations...

 ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] with non-zero mean : 9934.032

 Best model: Regression with ARIMA(1,0,3)(1,0,1)[7] errors
```

So the error for the `d = 0` model is less than the `d = 1` error.  A few questions:

1. Is `training_ts` truly stationary or is it "trend stationary"?  And if it is "trend stationary", I'll assume that means that when the trend is removed, the variance is stable vs. a truly stationary time series that has a stable variance without adjusting for the trend.
2. If `training_ts` is truly stationary, as `adf.test, kpss.test, nsdiffs` seem to suggest, why would `auto.arima` return a `d = 1` model with a higher error than the specified `d = 0` model?
3. If 'training_ts' is "trend-stationary", should I be using the 'd = 1' model?  I assumed that `auto.arima` would handle trend-stationary time series by removing the trend without a need to apply any differencing?

Thank you!

Comment: Post a link to your data

Answer (score 0):

For KPSS test, the null hypothesis is stationary. Since value is 0.01, it shows that series is non statoinary. Since Auto arima use KPSS test to test for stationary, it is differe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is on the right track in its first 2 sentences.